# Intercom welcome msg pop ups multiple times

Tags: chat, intercom

I am integrating Intercom into my website,which pop ups a welcome message for all new users. but the problem is the message pops up again and again ,every time i call intercoms update method with user json as parameter until i refresh the window. this happens only when user is logged in first time. 
Anybody knows how I can limit the welcome message to display only once for a user.

Answer (score 0):

Micheál here from the support team at Intercom.

Intercom will only deliver a given message to a user once so if you see a situation where the same message is being sent multiple times, it's likely something is interfering with the cookie we create.

This most commonly happens when using a domain with a public suffix e.g. my_awesome_website.herokuapp.com or similar.

If you're still having issues please drop us a line at team@intercom.io and we can investigate further